# Angular 13 router: Combining path parameters, query parameters and fragment into a single observable that updates only once per navigation event

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

In Angular 13 I have a route that evaluates query parameters, path parameters and the fragment.
Whenever a navigation to the route happens during which any number of the parameters changes, I want to handle all changes in one singe event.

Currently the component registered for the route combines the parameters into a single observable using `combineLatest`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([
      this.route.params, 
      this.route.queryParams, 
      this.route.fragment
    ])
    .pipe(map(p => {
      return { 
        id:         p[0]['id'],       // path parameter 'id'
        filter:     p[1]['filter'],   // query parameter 'filter'
        section:    p[2]              // fragment
      };
    }))
    .subscribe(p => {
      // handle parameter update
      // fetch data from backend
    });
  }
```

When navigating from route (id = 1, section = undefined) to route (id = 2, section = 1) using the `routerLink` directive, the code in the subscription is executed twice - first time for the change in the fragment (id = 1, section = undefined) --> (id = 1, section = 1) and a second time for the change of the id (id = 1, section = 1) --> (id = 2, section = 1).

Comment: This article https://blog.strongbrew.io/combine-latest-glitch/ suggests debounceTime(0). Haven't tried it - may not apply to your situation but probably worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by Barney in the comments works:
Including `debounceTime(0)` to the `map` solves the problem.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([
      this.route.params, 
      this.route.queryParams, 
      this.route.fragment
    ])
    .pipe(
      map(p => {
        return { 
          id:         p[0]['id'],       // path parameter 'id'
          filter:     p[1]['filter'],   // query parameter 'filter'
          section:    p[2]              // fragment
        };
      }), 
      debounceTime(0)                   // <--- SOLUTION !!!
    )
    .subscribe(p => {
      // handle parameter update
      // fetch data from backend
    });
  }
```